# Java Version Maven Issue

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a Java Project.
My System's Java version is 1.8
My Maven Version is pointed to 1.8 Java version

Now i intentionally added a nio package in my project. I ran the maven clean install before changing the pom.xml. Added below snippet

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
</properties
```

I expected the program to fail. But it was successful. Can anyone tell the reason why. i have also tried the snippet under plugin tag under build but to no avail. Please help

Comment: Maybe you have a maven-compiler-plugin with source and target tags in your pom - that override yours?

Comment: The intent was the "maven-compiler-plugin" with source and target tags to override the system's version which isn't happening as stated in the above question. Which is what is my problem

Comment: I meant, one can add to ones own pom the plugin, and when then also in the plugin configuration appears `<target>1.8</target>` I would not know what prevails. (But that seems not to be the case I understand.)

Comment: I did add the plugin in my own pom. Still it gets overriden by the system's version. Don't know why.

Comment: You could try in the plugin to add `<source>` and `<target>`.

Comment: Did that as well but to no avail .

Answer (score 0):

Java nio package exists in previous versions (like 1.5). Did you import one of the existins classes at that time? Perhaps you meant NIO.2?

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O_(Java))

Comment: import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
This is what i meant precisely which is under 1.7

Comment: Is it a multi module project? It is possible that the parent's plugin configuration overrides those properties.

Comment: Its a simple maven project. Without any parent pom or plugin configuration.

Comment: Perhaps I'm assuming much, but is it possible that you imported the Paths and Files classes from a java file's location that is not readable from maven (e.g. something other than src/main/java)? I don't think so, but just in case.